# Translate the sentence

Tags: translation

I can't figure out the problem with the boy in this sentence.

I looked up the phrase "tear off" in the dictionary, but when it goes with "except about two inches around", I found it hard to understand. Can anyone help me with this?

> "Ronnie was swinging on the swing and as he raised his arm to wave, his arm caught in the swing. His arm literally tore off all, except about two inches around."

Comment: ...all around his arm was torn off except two inches. This could be what is meant.

Comment: Thank you. About the phrase "tear off", does it mean the arm was ripped off/ got injured to the bones or it's just an external wound. "We rushed him to the hospital, the surgeon stitched it back on." The word "stitch" made me think it's an external wound. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, but here it says, 'tearing off...except two inches'.  That may not be ripping off.

Comment: Do you have any context for the passage? It sounds a bit drastic for a boy on a swing to have his entire arm ripped off. Could it refer to his sleeve?

Comment: As it stands, the quote claims that the arm tore everything (*else*) off, except for a 2-inch band. If the comma after "all" is moved to precede "all", the meaning changes entirely. Please verify that you've transcribed the text correctly, including punctuation.

Comment: The sentence isn't proper English, so it doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: This is the whole paragraph: "Ronnie was now one year old and we were now in the month of August - again. Ronnie was swinging on the swing and as he raised his arm to wave, his arm caught in the swing. His arm literally tore off all, except about two inches around. We rushed him to the hospital, the surgeon stitched it back on and today, after much prayer, he is fine." No incorrect punctuation :)) Thank you all for your help. If a native says it isn't proper English, maybe something is wrong with the original text.

Answer (score 0):

According to the text the unfortunate boy had his arm severed from his body. The only part left from the shoulder was 2 inches of arm. It is hard to believe this considering the amount of force needed and the angular momentum of a boy on as swing. But the description of going to the hospital seems to confirm the claim.

As for *Around* they could mean that *approximately 2 inches* were left meaning 2 inches of arm remained. As the comments say, the English is not without problems.

Comment: I've never heard "decapitate" used to refer to losing any part of the body other than the head.

Comment: The full quote added after your answer indicates that this was a toddler, so maybe it doesn't take much force to tear off their limb.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. That is surprising. I'm not aware of toddlers with enough awareness of their surroundings to wave at others. Even so the swing set would have to have been made by Mssr Guillotine to accomplish such a feat. 
As for *Decapitate* we could use the phrase "Chopped off" to take the meaning though I am still looking. I have landed on *Severed*.

Comment: "dismember" is the non-capital counterpart to "decapitate".